# Intervalo de hora entre datas ORACLE SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, data

Boa Tarde pessoal, Estou com uma dúvida no oracle SQL em que pra resolver eu queria pegar a seguinte informação:

Antes, tenho essa query:

```sql
SELECT  cd_atendimento,ds_atendimento,cd_valor,hr_atendimento
FROM  atendimento WHERE cd_atendimento IN
(
  5587064,
  5584065,
  5587654,
  4568985,
  5587062,
  5584061,
  5587659,
  4568910
)
AND hr_atendimento BETWEEN TO_DATE('01/11/2020 00:00:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
AND TO_DATE('11/11/2020 05:59:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
AND cd_atendimento IS NOT NULL
```

Eu queria que ele retornasse, Todos os atendimentos Do dia 01 até o dia 11 dentro das horas: 00:00 até 05:59, Seria um filtro por "DATA e hora Obviamente", ou seja ele teria que me retornar todos os atendimentos realizados entre essa hora de cada dia.

ex de retorno desejado :

```
Dia 01 de 00:00 as 05:59 : atendimentos: 5587064,
  5584065,
  5587654

Dia 02 de 00:00 as 05:59: atendimentos:5584061,
  5587659,
  4568910
```

e assim sucessivamente...

Podem me ajudar?, Pois do jeito que está ele vai me retornar desde o dia 01 as 00:00 até o dia 11 até as 05:59, o que não é o que eu preciso :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Separe data e hora
SELECT cd_atendimento,
           ds_atendimento,
           cd_valor,
           hr_atendimento 
    FROM atendimento 
    WHERE cd_atendimento IN ( 5587064, 5584065, 5587654, 4568985, 5587062, 5584061, 5587659, 4568910 ) 
    AND trunc(hr_atendimento) BETWEEN TO_DATE('01/11/2020', 'DD/MM/YYYY') AND 
                                      TO_DATE('11/11/2020', 'DD/MM/YYYY') 
    AND to_char(hr_atendimento,'hh24mi') BETWEEN '0000' and '0559'  
    AND cd_atendimento IS NOT NULL
```